# Как работает команда Update

Tags: база-данных, postgresql, транзакции

Подскажите, пожалуйста, правильно ли я понимаю, что последовательность команд

```
    BEGIN;
    UPDATE accounts SET balance = balance + 100.00 WHERE acctnum = 12345
    COMMIT;
```

будет выполняться следующим образом:

1. СУБД находит строку , соответствующую acctnum = 12345
2. СУБД накладывает эксклюзивную блокировку на найденную строку
3. СУБД считывает значение ячейки balance, далее изменяет это значение и записывает обратно
4. Выполняется команда COMMIT
5. СУБД снимает блокировку только после выполнения команды COMMIT

Заранее благодарю!

P.S. База данных Postgres, уровень изоляции транзакций READ COMMITED.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. выполняются before statement триггера
2. СУБД ищет строку, соответствующую acctnum = 12345
3. выполняет проверку, что эта версия строки видима текущей транзакции
4. если строку найти не удалось - переходим к п.14
5. выполняются before update for each row триггера. Если таковой существует, то выполняем манипуляции из п.8 и возвращаемся обратно сюда
6. проверяется существование instead of update триггера. Если есть - то выполняем их и продолжаем с п.14
7. если выполняем операцию над FDW таблицей - передаём дальнейшее управление FDW машинерии и продолжаем с п.14
8. достаём наиболее актуальную версию, попутно запрашивая пишущую блокировку на неё. Если какая-то транзакция удерживает блокировку - то ждём её и затем достаём возможно изменённую актуальную версию строки. Если транзакция завершилась rollback - то берём, конечно, не ту версию строки что пыталась сделать на транзакция, а последнюю зафиксированную. После разруливания блокировок и получения данных строки можем выяснить:

   - строка была удалена - тогда уходим на пункт п.14 (в том числе если сюда мы пришли из before update for each row триггера)
   - строка была изменена и более не подходит под требуемые условия поиска - аналогично уходим на пункт п.14
   - всё случилось, у нас есть блокировка строки и данные строки, продолжаем работать (возврат к п.5 если пришли оттуда)
9. выполняем в памяти требуемые операции обновления данных
10. помечаем строку удалённой, пишем в таблицу новую версию строки, добавляем в индексы сведения о новой версии строки
11. выполняются after update for each row триггера
12. формируем returning структуру, если применимо
13. переход на пункт 2
14. выполняются after statement триггера

Все взятые блокировки освобождаются только при завершении транзакции.

[Вот отсюда можно начать читать, ничего ли я не забыл описать важного и не напутал ли порядок](https://github.com/postgres/postgres/blob/REL_13_STABLE/src/backend/executor/nodeModifyTable.c#L2084).

Answer (score 0):

Да, в общем, правильно.

Есть только нюансы, если на шаге 2 выясняется, что строка уже заблокирована другой транзакцией. В этом случае события будут развиваться чуть по другому.

Когда блокировка другой транзакцией будет отпущена, то тут возможны два варианта. Если та другая транзакция сделала rollback, и значит ничего не поменяла в БД, то наша транзакция просто продолжит выполнение по описанным в вопросе шагам.

Если же другая транзакция сделала commit, то возможна ситуация, что условие `acctnum = 12345` уже не выполняется, поэтому оно заново проверяется. Если условие для строки все еще выполняется, то далее продолжается процесс с шага 2. Если же для стороки условие `acctnum = 12345` больше не выполняется, то в результате самой операции `UPDATE` ни одна строка не будет изменена. Выполнение продолжится, т.е. будет сделан COMMIT, транзакция завершена без изменения данных.

Comment: Всем спасибо!!!